# Terminology for metrics?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology, notation, metric-spaces

For some reason, I'm currently interested in the following relation - let $d,\delta$ be two metrics on some space $X$. We call the metrics _______ if there are some constants $C,E>0$ such that for all $x,y \in X$

$$
Cd(x,y)-E \le \delta(x,y) \le Cd(x,y)+E
$$

I was looking for a proper adjective to put in the blank spot. I was wondering if there was standard terminology for these kinds of metrics. If there are no standard ones, I would be happy to hear some suggestions.

Comment: Just to be sure: Do you want $C$ on both sides, not $C$ and $C^{-1}$? For $C$ and $C^{-1}$ that is a quasi-isometry, and with two $C$s the condition is stronger. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry

Comment: Yes, I do want the same $C$ on both sides. :-)

Comment: Then my guess is that it is not standard (but my guess may well be wrong). Since the condition resembles quasi-isometry, I might call it something like quasi-equivalence.

Comment: In this case, you can assume that $C=1$. In this case it is called $E$-isometry. Usually it is assumed that $E$ is small, but one does not have to do that. The identity map $(X,d)\to (X,\delta)$ is also called $E$-Hausdorff approximation. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

In the language of the paper "Embeddings of Gromov hyperbolic spaces" by Mario Bonk and Oded Schramm, the two metric spaces $(X,d)$ and $(X, \delta)$ you describe would be called **roughly similar**.

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a standard terminology, but some terminology have been proposed already.

In [*Elements of Asymptotic Geometry*](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Lao2mfi9bNUC&pg=PA199&lpg=PA199&dq=large-scale%20homothetic%20metrics&source=bl&ots=chna6fhR3H&sig=tDVL5kvxoD-80c9NTnE7RfVpbK4&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=7GkiVfvRJYPkaNT2gbAP&ved=0CC8Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=large-scale%20homothetic%20metrics&f=false) by Sergei Buyalo and Viktor Schroeder, this relation has been called **rough isometry** (up to minor notational change: there maps between metric spaces are considered rather than different metrics on the same space; so strictly speaking, in the vocabulary of Buyalo-Schroeder the identity map of $X$ is a rough isometry between $d$ and $\delta$.

I would bet that other words have been proposed for the same thing, and it would probably be difficult to find all proposed terminology; but you can start from the above reference, using citation databases and keywords you'll find in it to dig them up.

I would myself be in favor of a terminology of the kind of saying that $d$ and $\delta$ are **large-scale homothetic**, because homothety is the closest standard relation between metrics, and that your relation implies no small scale constraint at all.